# Inserir Data hoje input - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou dando manutenção em um código angular, porem não conheço muito a versão 1 desse framework, como eu coloco a data de hoje nesse input? alguem tem alguma ideia?

```
<input disabled type="text" class="form-control dateinput" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="panorama.start" is-open="startopened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2315-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Fechar" current-text="Hoje" clear-text="Limpar" style="width: 100px">
```

achei isso no codigo js

```
angular.module("panorama11App").controller("HeaderCtrl", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$filter", "panorama", "Config", function(a, b, c, d, e) {
    var myVar = '2015-10-10';
    a.open = function(b, c) {
        console.log("Opening..."), b.preventDefault(), b.stopPropagation(), a[c] = !0
    }, a.panorama = d, a.$watch("panorama", function() {
        d = a.panorama
    }), console.log("RouteParams:", b), a.config = e
}]),
```

no codigo tambem existe alguns returns assim:

```
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        title: "@",
        content: "@",
        "class": "@",
        dngmodel: "=",
        editable: "@",
        placeholder: "@"
    },
    controller: EditablespanCtrl,
    templateUrl: "views/editablespan.html"
}
```

será que se eu adicionar uma variavel ai eu consigo por ela no codigo ?

coloquei um id no meu input e adicionei um value nele, mas nao funciona

Comment: De onde vem `panorama.start`?

Comment: boa pergunta, estou procurando aqui

Comment: @Sergio fiz uma busca nos unicos arquivos javascript que contem nesta pagina, e não encontrei nenhuma definição de panorama.start

Comment: Faz uma busca por `.start`, ou por `.panorama `.

Comment: @Sergio ai aparece bastante coisa, coloquei um trecho do arquivo js, ps esse var = myVar (eu quem fiz pra teste )

Comment: @Sergio ainda não consegui :/ complicado,  nao sei nd de angular